Accessing Clipboard in Python version 3.11 with win32clipboard causing failed to open clipboard
this is my first question on stackoverflow, I apologize in case it is an unclear question,
I'm trying to create a productivity software where I manipulate the data I copy to the clipboard and paste the processed version (for now I split the text into rows and paste them individually) but every time I access the clipboard I don't have a safe method to not conflict with other processes or my program's processes (this is my assumption)
import win32clipboard
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import threading
import keyboard
import time


def check_clip():
    try:
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error access clipboard: {e}")
        return False

def run_safe(func):
    if check_clip():
        return func()
    else:
        #time.sleep(0.3)
        return run_safe(func)

def get_clipboard_text():
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    clipboard_text = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    return clipboard_text


def set_clipboard_text(text):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(text)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
        

def flush_clipboard():
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()


def get_next(column_list):
    run_safe(lambda: set_clipboard_text(column_list[0]))
    keyboard.wait('ctrl+v')
    while column_list:
        item = column_list.pop(0)
        run_safe(lambda: set_clipboard_text(item + "\n"))
        keyboard.wait('ctrl+v')
        run_safe(flush_clipboard)
    return True

def script():
    just_flushed = True
    while True:
        if program_running:    
            keyboard.wait('ctrl+c')
            time.sleep(0.3)
            column_text = run_safe(get_clipboard_text)
            column_list = column_text.splitlines()
            get_next(column_list)
            just_flushed = False
        else:
            if not just_flushed:
                run_safe(flush_clipboard)
                just_flushed = True


def main():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Controllo del Programma')],
        [sg.Button('Run/Stop', key='-STARTPAUSE-', button_color=('white','red'))],
    ]

    window = sg.Window('MemCP', layout)

    global program_running
    program_running = False
    program_thread = threading.Thread(target=script, daemon=True)
    program_thread.start()
    
    while True:
        event, values = window.read(timeout=100)

        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break

        if event == '-STARTPAUSE-':
            program_running = not program_running
            window['-STARTPAUSE-'].update(button_color=('white', 'green' if program_running else 'red'))        

    window.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


despite my workarounds every time I access clipboard data I randomly call for the exception to be thrown, is there a consistent method to solve my problem?
I tried to encapsulate all the functions that access it in these exception checking functions
def check_clip():
    try:
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error access clipboard: {e}")
        return False

def run_safe(func):
    if check_clip():
        return func()
    else:
        #time.sleep(0.3)
        return run_safe(func)

EDIT:
Error access clipboard: (5, 'OpenClipboard', 'Accesso negato.')
Exception in thread Thread-2 (script):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 982, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "c:\Users\marni\Desktop\clipboard\memory copypaste.py", line 62, in script
get_next(column_list)
File "c:\Users\marni\Desktop\clipboard\memory copypaste.py", line 49, in get_next
run_safe(lambda: set_clipboard_text(item + "\n"))
File "c:\Users\marni\Desktop\clipboard\memory copypaste.py", line 19, in run_safe
return func()
^^^^^^
File "c:\Users\marni\Desktop\clipboard\memory copypaste.py", line 49, in 
run_safe(lambda: set_clipboard_text(item + "\n"))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "c:\Users\marni\Desktop\clipboard\memory copypaste.py", line 32, in set_clipboard_text
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
pywintypes.error: (5, 'OpenClipboard', 'Accesso negato.')
the first one is the error caught by the try-except, I know maybe these kinds of expressions in development should be avoided but since the error is partially resolved but randomly appears anyway it was useful for me to test
2° EDIT: If someone is willing to reproduce the error, run the code, wait some time for the small window to appear, click the Run/Stop button once (it must become green), select a column of Excel or a text with multiple newline characters and ctrl + C, then hold ctrl + V on a blank document to paste the text rapidly (it probably step into the error and if don't, repeat with longer text source)

Don't make us guess what the error is and where it happens.  Please edit your question and add the full error traceback message.

Also, it's probably better to not have a try/except at all, at least during development, so you can see the full error.

What, EXACTLY, are you putting on the clipboard?  If the data is in a specific format, you'll have to ask for that format.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

I need only to copy text, for now, my only purpose of the question is to know if there are any ways to resolve the conflict in the access of the clipboard

I have edited the post twice. I hope that now you have all the information needed so someone can give me a bit of advice.
